# How to avoid blink when updating a ContentControl?

Tags: uwp

I have a `DataTemplate` defined as below.

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="singleUnit">
            <RelativePanel >
                <Button Padding="0,0,0,0" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Width="180" Height="210" Margin="0,0,70,20"
                        Style="{StaticResource textButtonStyle1}"
                        Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding itemIndex}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Image Source="{Binding icon_url, Converter={StaticResource _path2Image}}" Width="150" Height="150" Stretch="Uniform" Margin="0,0,0,0"/>
                        <Image Source="ms-appx:///Assets/SettingPage/Selected.png" Width="30" Height="30" Margin="130,-250,0,0"
                               Opacity="{Binding isSelected, Converter={StaticResource _selectedToOpacity}}"/>                           
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </RelativePanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

And I will assign the `DataTemplate` to a `ContentControl's` `ContentTemplate`. In the `DataTemplate`, it contains two Images(inside of a `Button`), one is main `Image`, another one is the corner icon(the `Marker`). And each time I need to update the corner icon only: to change its `Opacity` for 0 to 1 or ortherwise.

But when I use below code to get this function, I find sometimes the main `Image` will blink. I find some post from StackOverflow. Someone said it is caused by the `Button`'s trigger setting. But by Edit `Button`'s Copy, I do not find any key word of trigger now.

```
    private void SetMarker(int index)
    {
        ContentControl ccUnit = InitCCUnit(previousSelectedIndex, false);
        wrapGrid.Children[previousSelectedIndex] = ccUnit;

        ccUnit = InitCCUnit(index, true);
        wrapGrid.Children[index] = ccUnit;

        previousSelectedIndex = index;
    }

    private ContentControl InitCCUnit(int index, bool setMarked)
    {
        ContentControl ccUnit = new ContentControl();
        ccUnit.ContentTemplate = this.Resources["singleUnit"] as DataTemplate;

        if (setMarked)
            dms[index].isSelected = true;
        else
            dms[index].isSelected = false;

        ccUnit.Content = dms[index];
        return ccUnit;
    }
```

Code of `DataModel`: variable `dms` is the array which contains instance if `DataModel`

```
    public class DataModel
    {
        public string icon_url { get; set; }
        public int itemIndex { get; set; }
        public bool isSelected { get; set; }
        public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }
    }

    DataModel[] dms;
```

For example, there are total 6 Images. And I click two of them, named A and B.
When I click A, then the icon of A(a small tick icon) is shown(while Image of A is kept shown); at the same time the icon of B is hiden (while Image of B is kept shown). Or vice versa.

**Problem:**
Here when icon of B is hiden (means I click item A), then sometimes the Image of B will blink once. Not always. Why and how to solve it?

**More:**
I make a demo project to show this issue, pelase check this link to get the code:
https://github.com/tomxue/BlinkIssueInUWP.git

Richard mentioned using INotifyPropertyChanged, but I do not know how to combind it together with DataTemplate.

Comment: Hi Tom, If you can provide a minimum runnable demo, this will help us reproduce your problem more intuitively. In addition, the image blink may trigger re-rendering. You can try to make the `DataModel` implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Do not re-render when changing a single property.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT Thank you for your reply! Please check my main post, I provide the codes in GitHub. And I do not know how to use INotifyPropertyChanged for a DataTemplate element. Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I analyzed your code and found the cause of the blink.

The main reason is that you re-created the `ContentControl` and replaced the old one with a new one, which is not necessary.

Please try this:

1. Implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for the `DataModel`:

```cs
public class DataModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string icon_url { get; set; }
    public bool ssml_support { get; set; }
    public string data_name { get; set; }
    public string data_type { get; set; }
    public int itemIndex { get; set; }
    private bool _isSelected;
    public bool isSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    public ICommand ClickCommand { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

2. Rewrite `SetMarker` method:

```cs
private void SetMarker(int index)
{
    ContentControl ccUnit = wrapGrid.Children[previousSelectedIndex] as ContentControl;
    var previousContent = ccUnit.Content as DataModel;
    previousContent.isSelected = false;

    ContentControl currentUnit= wrapGrid.Children[index] as ContentControl;
    var currentContent = currentUnit.Content as DataModel;
    currentContent.isSelected = true;

    previousSelectedIndex = index;
}
```

This way, we don't need to create a new control, we just need to modify the state of the old control. This will not cause the so-called `blink` problem.